# Can we merge [visualization] and [data-visualization]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I was looking at the [visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualization) tag today and noticed we also have a [data-visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) tag.

This seems needlessly redundant, as most questions in [visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualization) are about data visualization anyways ([here's the <1/3 that **aren't**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvisualization%5D+-%5Bdata-visualization%5D+-plot+-figure+-graph+-data+is%3Aquestion+)).

Based on this, and the fact that visualization is the more general term, I vote we make [data-visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) a synonym of [visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualization) (or otherwise merge it in).

I don't see a reason to have these tags separate, especially as they're both currently attracting the same questions.

You can [upvote the synonym here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visualization/synonyms) or maybe a mod will come by and do it if this post gets enough upvotes itself.

---

If we really wanted to keep the tags separate, we would need to specify in [visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualization) that it is **not** for data visualization (as that's what it's mainly being used for currently), and change the tag for the ~2,500 [data-visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) questions mistagged as [visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualization).

Comment: They are contextual tags that matter a great deal to the *kind* of question being asked.  I would instantly skip them personally, good thing because that doesn't tickle me, but there are experts that don't and have a substantial number of answers in those tags.  A big hairy problem is that these tags don't have the same set of experts.  Pretty unclear why, to me, but a very good reason to not mess with them.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure I get what you mean, these two tags seems to attract exactly the same *kind* of question for the most part (namely, data-visualization questions). I'm also not seeing the disparate group of experts that you are, everyone I could find with substantial numbers of answers in one tag had quite a few in the other as well. Perhaps you're looking somewhere I'm not?

Comment: @pnuts I'd prefer a synonym, but those seem to happen rarely in tags that aren't massive, so a merge is acceptable as well. Also I wanted to note that your question is ambiguous (since I see you're copy pasting it other places). The natural answer I would give to it currently is "yes".